# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name index

Tags: asp.net, image, indexing

I want to Delete and Insert the Record but I have the error which is Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index I can't solve it please tell me how to solve it and yes I have the problem of Updating the Imge also please tell me how to update the image as well.

My Updating and Delete command DAC code is

```
public static bool UpdateStudent( string FirstName, string LastName, char Gender, float GPA, Byte[] MyImage)
        {
            bool success = false;
            string sql = "UPDATE Student SET FristName=@prmStudentFirstName,LastName=@prmLastName," +
                "Gender = @prmGender,GPA=@prmGPA,MyImage=@prmMyImage" +
                    "WHERE StudentID=@prmStudentID";
            using (SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand(sql,ConnectionManager.GetConnection()))
            {
               // command.Parameters.Add("@prmStudentID", SqlDbType.Int, 10).Value = StudentID;
                command.Parameters.Add("@prmFirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = FirstName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@prmLastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = LastName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@prmGender", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = Gender;
                command.Parameters.Add("@prmGPA", SqlDbType.Float).Value = GPA;
                command.Parameters.Add("@prmMyImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = MyImage;
                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                success = (rowsAffected == 1); 
            }
            return success;
        }
        public static bool DeleteStudent(string StudentID)
        {
            bool success = false;
            string sql = "DELETE FROM Student WHERE StudentID= @prmStudentID";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, ConnectionManager.GetConnection()))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@prmStudentID", SqlDbType.Int, 10).Value = StudentID;
                int rowAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                success = (rowAffected == 1);
            }
            return success;
        }
    }
```

My aspx.cs Code is

```
protected void studentGridview_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        StudentGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        DisplayStudentInformation();
    }
    protected void studentGridview_RowCancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        StudentGridView.EditIndex = -1;
        DisplayStudentInformation();
    }
    protected void studentGridview_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    { //Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
      //Parameter name: index
        string StudentID = ((Label)StudentGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("txtStudentID")).Text.ToString();
        string FirstName = ((TextBox)StudentGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtStudentFName")).Text;
        string LastName = ((TextBox)StudentGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtStudentLName")).Text;
        string Gender = ((TextBox)StudentGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtStudentGender")).Text;
        string GPA = ((TextBox)StudentGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtStudentGPA")).Text;
        //Problem as at blow line I cant set the Image for Updating it 
        string MyImage = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)StudentGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("Image")).ImageUrl;
        char studentGender = Convert.ToChar(Gender);
        float studentGPA = Convert.ToInt64(GPA);
        if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
        {
            byte[] ImageByteArray = null;
            ImageByteArray = ConvertImageToByteArray(FileUpload2);
            try
            {
                if (DAC.UpdateStudent( FirstName, LastName, studentGender, studentGPA, ImageByteArray))
                {
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Student" + StudentID + "Has been Updated Successfully.";
                    StudentGridView.EditIndex = -1;
                    DisplayStudentInformation();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void StudentGridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {     //Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
           //Parameter name: index
        string StudentID = ((Label)StudentGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("txtStudentID")).Text;
        try
        {
            if (DAC.DeleteStudent(StudentID))
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Student" + StudentID + "Has been Delted. ";
                DisplayStudentInformation();
            }
            else
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Student" + StudentID + "Could Not Be Delted.";
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

My .aspx code is

```
asp:ScriptManager ID="asm" runat ="server">
    /asp:ScriptManager>
    asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    div style="vertical-align: top; height:300px; width:100%; overflow:auto;">
    asp:GridView ID="StudentGridView" runat ="server" Height="302px" Width="800px" 
        BackColor ="White" BorderColor ="#999999" GridLines ="Vertical" 
        BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding ="3" 
           AutoGenerateColumns ="false" style="margin-top: 0px" 
EnableViewState ="false" OnRowEditing="studentGridview_RowEditing" 
           OnRowCancelingEdit="studentGridview_RowCancelEdit"  OnRowUpdating="studentGridview_RowUpdating" 
             OnRowDeleting="StudentGridView_RowDeleting" >
         Columns>
         asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="StudentID">
                ItemTemplate>
                  asp:Label ID ="txtStudentID" runat ="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentID") %>' />
                /ItemTemplate>
               /asp:TemplateField>
              asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="FirstName">
               ItemTemplate>
                 asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentFName" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
               /ItemTemplate>
              /asp:TemplateField>
              asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="LastName">
               ItemTemplate>
                 asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentLName" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
               /ItemTemplate>
              /asp:TemplateField>
              asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Gender">
               ItemTemplate>
                 asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentGender" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Gender") %>' />
               /ItemTemplate>
              /asp:TemplateField>
              asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="GPA">
               ItemTemplate>
                 asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentGPA" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("GPA") %>' />
               /ItemTemplate>
              /asp:TemplateField>
               asp:TemplateField  HeaderText ="Images">
                ItemTemplate>
                 asp:Image ID ="Image" runat ="server" Height ='30px' Width ='30px' ImageUrl ='<%# "Handler.ashx?StudentID="+Eval("StudentID") %>' />

                /ItemTemplate>
               /asp:TemplateField>
               asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" CausesValidation ="false" />
               asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" CausesValidation="false" />
              /Columns>     
        HeaderStyle BackColor ="#0000B4" Font-Bold ="true" ForeColor ="White" Font-Size="Small" />
        EditRowStyle BackColor ="#00ABC" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" font-Size="Small" />
        AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" Font-Size="Small" />
        SelectedRowStyle BackColor ="#00ABAC" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor ="White" Font-Size="Small" />
    /asp:GridView>
    /div>
    asp:Table runat="server" Height="16px" Width="78px">
     asp:TableRow>
     asp:TableCell ><asp:Image ID ="AddStudentRecord" runat ="server"  Width="100" Height ="50" ImageUrl="~/images/AddStudentRecord.JPG"/></asp:TableCell>
     /asp:TableRow>
     asp:TableRow>
        asp:TableCell>
           asp:Panel CssClass="modal" ID ="ModalPanel"  ScrollBars="Vertical" runat ="server" Width="950" Height="90" style="display:none">
             asp:Table runat ="server">
                asp:TableRow>
                  asp:TableCell>
                      asp:Label ID="StudentIDLabel" runat ="server" Text="Student ID">/asp:Label>
                  /asp:TableCell>
                  asp:TableCell>
                      asp:Label ID="StudentFirstNameLabel" runat ="server" Text="Student FirstName"></asp:Label>
                  /asp:TableCell>
                  asp:TableCell>
                      asp:Label ID="StudentLastNameLabel" runat ="server" Text="Student LastName"></asp:Label>
                  /asp:TableCell>
                  asp:TableCell>
                      asp:Label ID="StudentGenderLabel" runat ="server" Text="Student Gender"></asp:Label>
                  /asp:TableCell>
                  asp:TableCell>
                      asp:Label ID="StudentGPALabel" runat ="server" Text="Student GPA">/asp:Label>
                  /asp:TableCell>
                  asp:TableCell>
                      asp:Label ID="StudentImageLabel" runat ="server" Text="Student Image"></asp:Label>
                  /asp:TableCell>
                /asp:TableRow>
                  asp:TableRow>
                      asp:TableCell>
                          asp:TextBox ID="StudentIDTextBox" runat ="server"></asp:TextBox> 
                      /asp:TableCell>
                      asp:TableCell>
                          asp:TextBox ID="StudentFirstNameTextBox" runat ="server">/asp:TextBox> 
                      /asp:TableCell>
                      asp:TableCell>
                          asp:TextBox ID="StudentLastNameTextBox" runat ="server">/asp:TextBox> 
                      /asp:TableCell>
                      asp:TableCell>
                          asp:TextBox ID="StudentGenderTextBox" runat ="server">/asp:TextBox> 
                      /asp:TableCell>
                      asp:TableCell>
                          asp:TextBox ID="StudentGPATextBox" runat ="server">/asp:TextBox> 
                      /asp:TableCell>
                      asp:TableCell>
                          asp:Image ID="StudentImage" ImageUrl="" Width="25px" Height ="25px" runat="server" />                          
                      /asp:TableCell> 
                  /asp:TableRow>
                      asp:TableRow>
                         asp:TableCell ColumnSpan ="4" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                             asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat ="server" Text="Add"  />&nbsp;
                             asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat ="server" Text ="Cancel" />
                             /asp:TableCell>                
                         asp:TableCell >   
                      /asp:TableCell>
                      asp:TableCell   HorizontalAlign="left">
                           asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
                           asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload"  OnClick="UploadButton_Click"  />
                      /asp:TableCell>
                      /asp:TableRow>
              /asp:Table>
           /asp:Panel> 
           cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
           TargetControlID="AddStudentRecord" PopupControlID="ModalPanel" BackgroundCssClass ="modalBackground" />
```

Please tell me who to solve this error and also consider my Image updating logic I am not sure that my logic is right or wrong.

Comment: Whoa, consider editing your post for legibility.  Separate your comments from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this stood out straight off

```
Gender = @prmGender,GPA=@prmGPA,MyImage=@prmMyImage" + "WHERE StudentID=@prmStudentID";
```

should be

```
Gender = @prmGender,GPA=@prmGPA,MyImage=@prmMyImage" + " WHERE StudentID=@prmStudentID";
```

Because at the moment Gender will be

```
"@prmGender,GPA=@prmGPA,MyImage=@prmMyImageWHERE StudentID=@prmStudentID";
```

I'm guessing the field name FristName may be your next issue as well. :)

Comment: I solve the firstName issue as well bu i don't understand about the two above line for Well this stood out straight off and for the should be as will please tell me what you mean about these above to lines

Comment: And error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name index still exist as it was

Comment: Thanks for helping me but i have problem of updating the image column still my other records can be updated but image having same problem sir so please in my new post help me please please

Comment: Index out of bounds still? Or an other issue?

Comment: No Issue of Index out of bounds have been solve but problem is that when i try to update the image then image is updated but when i try to update other records accept the image then error is occure .It means to update the record i have to update the image as well but i don't want to do it i mean when ever i require to update the image then i update the image other wise i just update the other record ok so in my new post you can see it that how i modify my code and where i talk a logical mistake ok sir thanks for helping me and replaying to me thanks very much

Comment: Which is MyImage a string (the url) or the image itself? You seem to have a mixture. Given you've set the param to varbinary, I'd have expected that to be a ByteArray of the image stream, not the url. If you want to update evereything but the image, just have an other query that updates everthing else and leaves that alone.